# Simple Key Listeners

Tags: java, swing, keyboard, keylistener, key-bindings

Alright, so I'm making a simple pong game as my first real Java project. My "racquet" on the bottom of the JFrame works and all, except for the motion part. I need to be able to read input from my keyboard. I know this can be done through the KeyListener (I think) method; and the Java documentation website tells me I can bind certain keys to certain actions. Which way is the most efficient/easiest; and if so, what's the simplest way to implement it? I realize it isn't as simple as

```
if(keypressed == VK_LEFT) 
    do something
```

but I've been having a terrible time trying to figure these dang things out. Help please?

Answer (score 4):

[Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) are generally the preferred method and tend to be less trouble some

```
InputMap im = getInputMap();
ActionMap am = getActionMap();

im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK), "left");
im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK), "right");

am.put("left", new AbstractAction() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // Code to go left
    }
});
am.put("right", new AbstractAction() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // Code to right
    }
});
```

What's really cool is if you create the `Action`s as separate classes, you could use the same `Action`s on `JButton`s!

Comment: Eclipse tells me that getInput/Actionmap() is undefined for my class; how would I go about defining it?

Comment: What is your class extending from?  `getInputMap` and `getActionMap` are methods of `JComponent` - Key bindings can only be applied to `JComponent`s and it's children...

Comment: Ah, It wasn't extending from anything. I changed that to JComponent and the errrors fixed themselves. However, does the keybinding require that that I initialize it in the main code? Currently it sits as a method of my class Racquet, but I don't think it gets called when I initialize a new instance of Racquet.

Comment: You can initialise the key bindings when ever you want, but until you do, nothing will respond to the key strokes